# How to find matching partial items from two list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Good day.

I have the following 2 list that I need to compare for a match. I need to find if listB items are in listA and then return the item in listA.

```
listA = ['abcd755 - (45)', 'abcd754 - (32.12)', '3xas34a - (43.23)', '01shdsa - (0.01)']
listB = ['abcd754', '23xas34a', 'abcd755', '01shdsa']
out = []

for b in listB:
    if any(a.startswith(b) for a in listA):
        out.append(b)

print (out)
```

Current Output:

```
['abcd754', 'abcd755', '01shdsa']
```

Intended Output:

```
['abcd754 - (32.12)', 'abcd755 - (45)' , '01shdsa - (0.01)']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use assignement operator `:=`:

```py
listA = ['abcd755 - (45)', 'abcd754 - (32.12)', '3xas34a - (43.23)', '01shdsa - (0.01)']
listB = ['abcd754', '23xas34a', 'abcd755', '01shdsa']
out = []

for b in listB:
    if any((c := a).startswith(b) for a in listA):
        out.append(c)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['abcd754 - (32.12)', 'abcd755 - (45)', '01shdsa - (0.01)']
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop over listA instead of listB.

```py
listA = ['abcd755 - (45)', 'abcd754 - (32.12)', '3xas34a - (43.23)', '01shdsa - (0.01)']
listB = ['abcd754', '23xas34a', 'abcd755', '01shdsa']
out = []

for a in listA:
    if any(a.startswith(b) for b in listB):
        out.append(a)

print (out)

#['abcd755 - (45)', 'abcd754 - (32.12)', '01shdsa - (0.01)']
```